# Simple search engine in my Django Web is not working

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, web

I'm trying to make my search go over my query my Database in Django.

The lines in form.is_valid() is other forms I added to my website of adding data and it works perfect.
The only thing is that query thing..
I just don't understand why after I click search I still see the all posts and not the posts I search for..

views.py-

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):

    template_name = 'serverlist.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = HomeForm()
        query = request.GET.get("q")
        posts = serverlist.objects.all()
        args = {'form' : form, 'posts' : posts}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)

    def post(self,request):
        form = HomeForm(request.POST)
        posts = serverlist.objects.all()

        query = request.GET.get("q")
        if query:
            posts = serverlist.filter(Project__icontains=query)

        if form.is_valid(): # Checks if validation passed
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
            text = form.cleaned_data['ServerName']
            form = HomeForm()
            return redirect('serverlist')
        args = {'form': form, 'text': text}
        return render(request, self.template_name,args)
```

index.html -

```
<div class="container">

    <br>
    <center><h1>DevOps Server List</h1></center>
    <br>
    <form method='GET' action=''>
        <input type='text' name='q' placeholder='Search Item'/>
        <input type='submit' value='Search' />
    </form>
    <table class="table table-hover">
    <thread>

      <tr>
        <th> Server Name </th>
        <th> Owner </th>
    <th> Project </th>
    <th> Description </th>
    <th> IP Address </th>
    <th> ILO </th>
    <th> Rack </th>
    <th> Status </th>
    <th>  </th>


</tr>
</thread>
<tbody>

            {% for server in posts %}

    <tr>
      <div class ="server">
        <td>{{ server.ServerName }}</td>
        <td>{{ server.Owner }}</td>
        <td>{{ server.Project }}</td>
        <td>{{ server.Description }}</td>
        <td>{{ server.IP }}</td>
        <td>{{ server.ILO }}</td>
        <td>{{ server.Rack }}</td>
        <td>{{ server.Status }}</td>

        <td>
```

forms.py -

```
class HomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ServerName = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput,max_length = 30)
    Owner = forms.CharField(max_length = 50)
    Project = forms.CharField(max_length = 30)
    Description = forms.CharField(max_length = 255)
    IP = forms.CharField(max_length = 30)
    ILO = forms.CharField(max_length = 30)
    Rack = forms.CharField(max_length = 30)
    Status = forms.CharField(max_length = 30)
    class Meta:
        model = serverlist
        fields = ('ServerName' ,'Owner','Project','Description','IP','ILO','Rack','Status',)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add filter to your get methods:

```
posts = serverlist.objects.all() 
query = request.GET.get("q")
if query:
    posts = serverlist.objects.filter(Project__icontains=query)
    #                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: did you return search form method to the `GET`?

Comment: Yes. The form is now using GET
Maybe it still do posts = serverlist.objects.all() somehow.. weird

Comment: Searching Devops -
http://172.16.10.60:8000/?q=DevOps

It seem like the HTML is ok but the problem is with the views somehow

Comment: try `posts = serverlist.objects.none()` just to understand is your posts get correctly, you should get empty list

Comment: So when I do it under post function there is no change at all... (It seem like I didn't even need to do posts=serverlist.object.all() under post because it gets the info from get.

When I do it under the get function it clears the data..
So maybe I should do the search under get function?
Or it is better to change the form to POST and keep the views as it is like @scriptmonster said?

Comment: I think I solved it:
def get(self, request):
        form = HomeForm()
        query = request.GET.get("q")
        posts = serverlist.objects.all()

        if query:
            posts = serverlist.objects.filter(Project__icontains=query)
        else:
            posts = serverlist.objects.all()
   

The question is.. how do I filter many colums and not only project

Comment: added your solution to the answer

Comment: posts = serverlist.objects.filter(Project__icontains=query)
Where?
I still see you search only project..
How can I search Project or ServerName or.. like all the Databases columns?

Comment: i'm go offline, you need to create a question with model and query you want

Comment: Sure, I will add a new one. Thanks bro!

Answer (score 0):

you are performing the search in the post method. Thus you need to send data with POST method. Please change the method in the form tag as follows.

```
<form method='POST' action=''>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type='text' name='q' placeholder='Search Item'/>
    <input type='submit' value='Search' />
</form>
```

> When you use POST method you will need csrf tooken as well. `{% csrf_token %}` template tag is used for that purpose.

BTW you are using a form object to validate your form. But you created the form manually in your template. You should use it to create HTML too. Thus your template will be like this:

```
<form method='POST' action=''>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type='submit' value='Search' />
</form>
```

This could solve your problem about form not being valid. Since you did not share your HomeForm sources, I cannot tell.

Comment: You maybe right!
But the problem is that I get this error when I do the post- 

UnboundLocalError at /
local variable 'text' referenced before assignment

I got this error many times and I don't know what to put on text..
I think it waits for data as text in other forms I use to add data to the website and when it's empty (Because I just do search) it says I use text even thought it doesn't contain any data (because the forms for adding the server is empty)

Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: @scriptmonster usually for search form use `GET` method it allowed to exchange search results.

Comment: Since you did not assign text variable before the if statement, and your form seems to be invalid, thus it gives you unbound error.
@BearBrown You are right, this could be a better use. I am thinking this as a simple form application.

Comment: @EilonAshkenazi Please check my last update about rendering your form directly and check if it's working for you.

Comment: I added the forms.py
But are you sure I should do the form as post and not as get like @BearBrown suggested?

Comment: Nope, I am not sure after you shared the forms.py. You need to follow @BearBrown 's answer.

Comment: @BearBrown Answer was correct.
The only thing left.. how do I search in more colums and not only Project?